Polynomial solution of second-order differential equation

$\ddot{y}-2t\dot{y}+3y=0 \quad(\ast)$

I want to investigate if there is any polynomial solution for the given differential equation
Considering $y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nt^n$ and substituting above in $(\ast)$:
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n}+3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n=0 \\[10pt]
  \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}t^{n}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n}+3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n=0 \\[10pt]
  \implies 2a_2+3a_0+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigr[ (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-2na_n+3a_n\bigr]t^{n}=0
\end{align*}
If I assume that $a_0=0$, then $a_{2n}=0; n \in \mathbb{N}$, because $a_{n+2}=\frac{(2n-3)a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}$. And if I let $a_1=1$ and I'd obtain:
$$a_{2k+1}=\frac{(4k-5)a_{2k-1}}{(2k+1)(2k)}; a_{2k+1}=\frac{(4k-5)(4k-9) \dots (-1)}{(2k+1)!}$$
and this'd lead to a power series that is a solution of $(\ast)$. Then I should find another solution letting for example $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$? And calculating their Wronskian; I should conclude that there won't be any non-null polynomial solution if $W[y_1,y_2](0) \neq 0$?

You're overcomplicating this. If you're interested in polynomial solutions, don't substitute a power series. What degree could a polynomial solution have?

Related problem by same poster: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4904483/determining-values-of-a-parameter-for-which-an-initial-value-problem-has-a-polyn

There is a simpler way to show that $(*)$ does not have a nonzero polynomial solution. Indeed, if such a solution existed, say $y(t)=t^{n}+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0$, then it would satisfy
$$
\ddot{y}-2t\dot{y}+3y=(-2n+3)t^{n}+\ldots+(2a_2+3a_0)=0. \tag{1}
$$
However, there is no integer $n\geq 0$ such that $-2n+3=0$, so $(1)$ cannot be satisfied. $\square$
