Determining values of a parameter for which an initial value problem has a polynomial solution
Given the following IVP:
\begin{cases}
\ddot{y}-3t\dot{y}-ky=0\\
y(0)=1; \; \dot{y}(0)=0
\end{cases}
I want to determine the possible values of $k$ in order to obtain a polynomial solution; if $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+ \dots + t^n$ would be a solution; then $a_0=1; a_1=0$; so I'd get $p(t)=1+ a_2t^2+ \dots + t^n$ and I also have that:
$$(-3n-k)t^n=0 \iff k=-3n$$
But now I just could find solutions for $k=-6n$, i.e., for $\ddot{y}-3t\dot{y}+6ny=0$ with a polynomial of degree $2n$ as solution but I can't find a way to reason why shouldn't exist a polynomial solution for $k=-3-6n$.  Any suggestions?

$p(t)=t$ is a solution for $k=-3$.

And $p(t)=t^3-t$ is a solution for $k=-9$.

@Gonçalo Those equations do not satisfy $y(0) = 1$.

Those solutions to the equation alone still illustrate an important point, that we need to use the initial conditions to draw the conclusion. I've mentioned your observations in my answer.

As you've already computed, substituting the general polynomial ansatz
$$y(t) = a_n t^n + a_{n - 1} t^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1 t + a_0$$
into the given differential equation,
$$\ddot y - 3 t \dot y - k y = 0 $$
gives the equation
\begin{multline}\color{#bf0000}{(-3 n - k) a_n} t^n + \color{#bf0000}{(-3 (n - 1) - k) a_{n - 1}} t^{n - 1} \\
+ \sum_{j = 1}^{n - 2} \color{#bf0000}{[(j + 2) (j + 1) a_{j + 2} - (3 j + k) a_j]} t^j + \color{#bf0000}{(2 a_2 - k a_0)} = 0 ,
\end{multline}
and the polynomial is a solution iff all of the coefficients vanish. We may as well assume $a_n \neq 0$, so that the vanishing of the coefficient of the degree $n$ term imposes precisely that $k = -3 n$.
Hint As @Gonçalo points out in the comments, without imposing the initial conditions there are polynomial solutions to the differential equation when $k = - (3 + 6 n)$, $n \geq 0$, e.g., $k = -3$, $y(t) = t$. So, to eliminate those cases it's necessary to use the initial conditions. We have $a_1 = \dot y(0) = 0$; what does the vanishing of the terms $(j + 2) (j + 1) a_{j - 2} - 3 a_j$, $j = 1, \ldots, n - 2$ then tell you?

 Solving inductively gives that $a_j = 0$ for all odd $j$. Since $a_n \neq 0$, $n$ must be even, say, $n = 2 m$, so $k = -6 m$. On the other hand, for such $k$ induction gives an formula for $a_n$, which establishes the existence of a solution.

Remark We can actually identify the polynomial solutions explicitly. Changing variables via $y(t) = t u(t)$ and $\tau = \frac32 t^2$ transforms the equation to Kummer's equation with parameters $\mu = \frac12 + \frac{k}6$, $\nu = \frac32$:
$$u''(\tau) + \left(\frac32 - \tau\right) u'(\tau) - \left(\frac12 + \frac{k}6\right) u(\tau) = 0 .$$ One solution is $$u(\tau) = \tau^{-\frac12} M\left(\frac{k}6, \frac12; \tau\right),$$ where $M$ is Kummer's function. In particular, for $k = -6 m$, $m \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, the first parameter is a nonpositive integer, and
$$L_m^{\left(-\frac12\right)}(\tau) = M\left(-m, -\frac12; \tau\right)$$ is the $m$th generalized Laguerre polynomial with parameter $\alpha = -\frac12$. Changing variables back to $y(t)$ and scaling to satisfy the initial conditions gives an explicit formula for the (unique) polynomial solution with $k = -6 m$, namely
$$y(t) = \frac{(2 m)!!}{(2 m - 1)!!} L_m^{\left(-\frac12\right)}\left(\frac32 t^2\right) ,$$
which has degree $2 m$, and where $\cdot !!$ (unfortunately) denotes the double factorial. The first few solutions are
\begin{array}{cl}
\hline
k & y(t) \\
\hline
  0 & 1 \\
- 6 & 1 - 3 t^2 \\
-12 & 1 - 6 t^2 + 3 t^2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
A similar (but easier) observation shows that for $k = - (3 + 6 n)$, $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, the polynomial solutions (of the equation, but not the initial conditions) are again expressible in terms of generalized Laguerre polynomials.

It turns out that the only polynomial solutions to this BVP occur when $k=-6m$ with $m\geq 0$ an integer. In fact, the unique solution for this equation is obtainable using series methods, and can be written in terms the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function, and you can characterize exactly when it is a polynomial from a formula if you want: computer algebra systems are capable of giving exact answers to this type of problem.
But that wouldn't be particularly enlightening, so let's see if we can solve the problem by hand. What you are missing from your argument are the conditions on all the other coefficients, and a check for whether they are consistent.
Writing $y(t) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_jt^j$, the boundary-value problem imposes certain conditions that the coefficients $a_j$, as well as $k$ and $n$, must satisfy. Some of these you've already discovered, like $a_0=1,a_1=0, k=-3n$. But:

The ODE and boundary conditions also imply conditions on the remaining coefficients $a_j$, $j\neq 0,1$, which you have not taken into account.
These conditions on the coefficients are necessary conditions for a solution, but there is no a priori guarantee that the conditions can actually be satisfied. That's something we have to do the extra work to check, and in the process we will likely encounter additional implications that must be satisfied - or are inconsistent with the earlier conditions.
Requiring a monic polynomial $a_n=1$ for the solution might be one condition too many to allow a consistent solution. Haven't checked this thoroughly, but it could be what's tripping you up.

So what happens when we do check the conditions? Well, if we plug $y(t)$ into the BVP we will find that the coefficients satisfy the following conditions:
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0 = 1,\\
a_1 = 0,\\
2a_2 - ka_0 = 0,\\
(3j+k)a_j = 0 & \text{for}~ j=n-1, n,\\
(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2} - (3j+k)a_j = 0 & \text{for}~j=1,\ldots,n-2.
\end{cases}
$$
We can then start inductively solving for the remaining coefficients. For instance, you've already noted that since we can assume $a_n\neq 0$ without loss of generality, the $j=n$ case implies $k=-3n$, which we can now plug back into all of the remaining equations. Immediately this implies $a_{n-1}=0$. The condition $a_1 = 0$ feeds into the last equation for $j=1$, and implies $3a_3 = 0$, hence $a_3 = 0$ (if $n > 3$ of course - otherwise we already have all the necessary coefficients). Similarly, we can work down from $a_{n-1}=0$ to show that $a_{n-3} = 0$ (assuming $n$ is large enough that $a_{n-3}$ is yet undetermined by the previous conditions).
What we find is that we can bootstrap our way up and down the chain of recurrences. Going up from $a_1$ makes $a_3$ vanish, which makes $a_5$ vanish, and so on: the intermediate coefficients vanish for odd $j$. Similarly, going down from $j+2 = n-1$ makes $n-3$ vanish, then $n-5$, and so on. If $n$ is even, then $n-1$ is odd, and going down from $n-1$ makes the odd $j$ coefficients vanish; when $n$ is odd, then the even $j$ coefficients vanish.
The latter case, $n$ odd, is incompatible with $2a_2 - ka_0 = 0$, i.e. $a_2 = \frac{k}{2}$, unless $k=0$. In this case the equation is actually a first-order ODE for $\dot{y}$ that we can solve explicitly, and we find that the boundary conditions imply $y$ is constant, which has a single solution: $y(t)=1$. This being a $0$-th degree polynomial, it turns out we can't actually satisfy this case with a polynomial of strictly odd degree polynomial, but this is fine.
The former case, $n$ even, runs into no contradictions, so we can compute the coefficients $a_j$ whenever $n$ is even. The recurrences simplify to
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0 = 1,\\
a_2 = \frac{k}{2},\\
a_j = 0 & \text{for}~j~\text{odd},\\
(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2} - (3j+k)a_j = 0 & \text{for}~j=2,\ldots,n-2.
\end{cases}
$$
Note that we can always solve the final recurrence inductively, starting from $j=2$ (which is known, given a value of $k$).
Since $k = -3n$ and $n$ must be even, it follows that $k$ is either zero (when $n=0$, which is covered by the previous case) or a negative multiple of $6$. In conclusion, we can find a polynomial solution whenever $k$ is a nonpositive integer multiple of $6$. One example of such a solution, with $k=-6$ (i.e. $n=2$) is $y(t) = 1-3t^2$. For $k=-12$, i.e. $n=4$, we can verify that $y(t) = 1-6t^2-3t^4$ is solution, and so on. We can also verify that this agrees with the solution provided by computer algebra systems in terms of the Kummer hypergeometric function.
